# How to remove 'edit access' from query on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, permissions, google-bigquery

I have a sheet that gets data from BigQuery and everybody can edit. I tried to remove permissions in the tab with a query, but it didn't work because it's connected to a database. Here is the error:

> Can't add protection to this sheet because it's connected to a database.

[image: "Can't add protection to this sheet because it's connected to a database"]

How do I remove query edit permission without removing edit access in all the sheet?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the [documentation for this feature under "Change who can see & edit queries or results"](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9077536), to edit the BigQuery query, the user needs both a corresponding BigQuery role and at least the editor permission in the Sheet.

When users don't have a proper BigQuery role, they will get an error like this:

[image: Access Denied error]

So, as long as the users don't have the required permissions for BigQuery in your project, then they won't be able to edit the query. A user with no role in BigQuery can only see fetched data from a BigQuery query and view the query itself.

If you have users who have BigQuery roles in your project, you can separate the Google Sheet to a file where the users only have viewer permissions for the Sheets file.